# Divine language(s) in Islam?

Tags: language

As we know that Sanskrit is considered as divine language in Hinduism, I want to know Is there any language that is considered as diving in Islam. or Which are the divine language of Islam?

Comment: If you check the wikipedia site on Islam https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islam to which language all of the terms refer?

Comment: *Sanskrit is considered as divine language in Hinduism* No, it isn't. Most, **but not all**, of the Hindu scriptures are written in Sanskrit, but it is not eulogised or held to be divine in the religion.